# How do I get my Bit coin balance to restore on my new phone?

Tags: user-base

My phone broke and is unusable and I am new to the whole bit coin service. I switched phones and downloaded the bit coin wallet how do I get my balance back?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't make a backup, sorry you are out of luck you cannot get your Bitcoin back. It could be possible get to some information out of your old phone (like sd card or some other way of restoring info, but this completely depends on which kind of phone you had or how broken it is)

If you made a backup you have to restore it. This process depends on the used wallet app. I would recommend downloading the same wallet app as you used on your old phone, they are most of the time not compatible. Some apps tell you to write down a set of words when you create a wallet. You could use these words to restore your wallet. Some wallets need a file which you have to have in order to restore the backup.